# How to get the textarea ID using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

Ive got textarea area on each table row with unique ID .
How to retrieve that unique id with javascript?

PHP:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bs_events WHERE eventDate = '".$date."'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo '<textarea id=\"att_name_" . $row['id'] . "\" style=\"width:300px\"></textarea>";'
}
```

PHP OUTPUT:

```
<textarea id="att_name_1" style="width:300px">  
<textarea id="att_name_2" style="width:300px">
<textarea id="att_name_3" style="width:300px">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#book_event").submit(function(){
       id = event.target.id.replace('att_name_','');
       $.post("Scripts/book_event.php", { 
            att_name: $("att_name_"+id).val(),
       }, function(data){
            if(data.success) {
               $("#err").text(data.message).fadeIn("slow");
            }
       }, "json");

   });   
});
```

Comment: How do you determine which one you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're naming your textareas to correlate to the database entries, then trying to make updates and pass those values back. Assuming the textareas are in the form you're submitting, you can use:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
  // find each of those text areas
  $(this).find('textarea[id^=att_name]').each(function(i,e){
    //
    // from here-in, e now represents one of those textareas
    //

    // now submit the update
    $.post('Scripts/book_event.php',{
      att_name: $(e).val()
    },function(data){
      if (!data.success)
        $("#err").text(data.message).fadeIn("slow");
    },'json');
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Ideally though, if you're looking to use AJAX to push updates/changes back to the server, you may look in to [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and push all forms back. Then, on the server-side you'll get the standard `$_POST['att_name_1']` values that you can use for your actual updating. e.g.

```
// .serialize() example
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
  $.post('Scripts/book_event.php',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    if (!data.success)
      $("#err").text(data.message).fadeIn("slow");
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you can use each()

```
$(function()
{
    $("textarea").each(function()
    {
       var textarea_id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the question.

If you want a list of the ids, how about something like:

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
    var textareas = new Array();

    // Run through each textbox and add the id to an array
    $("textarea").each( function( ) {
        textareas.push( $(this).attr("id") );
    });

    // Print out each id in the array
    textareas.forEach( function(i) { alert(i); });

 });
```

(that's untested and probably not the quickest way - I'm a bit out of practice)